# Modify images in ThisWorkbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have an add-in that contain a spreadsheet. I need to update this spreadsheet with text, images and formatting from another sheet.

The code used to do that is:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("START").Cells.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("START").Range("A1")
```

The problem is that the images that is copied is not the same size or aspect ratio as the original. 
I tried to paste-special the images as .tif, .jpeg and .bmp in the source sheet with no success. 
I also tried to change the height on the ThisWorkbook but it does not seem to allow changing the images.

If anyone can suggest a way to either copy the images with original size or to change the size it will be most helpful.